# How to solve No matching Route53Zone found?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-route53

I'm working on creating a module for terraform AWS certification manager in terraform > 0.12 Version. I noticed that when `var.domain_name=["x.public.com","y.private.dev"]`has both public  and private domains, I'm getting an error `no matching Route53Zone found`.

I did manually run `aws route53 list-hosted-zones-by-name`, I was able to get both public and private zone id's , also it worked when `var.domain_name=["x.public.com"] or var.domain_name=["y.private.dev"]`, ie only all public or all private.

I'm not sure what the issue is? I tried removing `private_zone`, & also tried  with `private_zone = trimprefix(each.value,".") == "dev" ? "true" : "false"`, in both cases got the same error.

Can someone point me where i'm wrong. Thanks!

Code:

```
resource "aws_acm_certificate" "certificate" {
  for_each                  = toset(var.domain_name)
  domain_name               = each.value
  subject_alternative_names = ["*.${each.value}"]
  validation_method         = "DNS"

  tags = {
    Name  = each.value
    owner = "foo"
  }

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}

data "aws_route53_zone" "selected" {

  for_each     = toset(var.domain_name)
  name         = each.value
  private_zone = false
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "record" {
  for_each = toset(var.domain_name)
  zone_id = data.aws_route53_zone[each.key].selected.zone_id 
  name    = aws_acm_certificate.certificate[each.key].domain_validation_options.0.resource_record_name
  type    = aws_acm_certificate.certificate[each.key].domain_validation_options.0.resource_record_type
  ttl     = "300"
  records = [aws_acm_certificate.certificate[each.key].domain_validation_options.0.resource_record_value]
}


Error: no matching Route53Zone found

  on ../tf_module_acm/main.tf line 1, in data "aws_route53_zone" "selected":
   34: data "aws_route53_zone" "selected" {


Error: no matching Route53Zone found

  on ../tf_module_acm/main.tf line 1, in data "aws_route53_zone" "selected":
   34: data "aws_route53_zone" "selected" {
```

Comment: 1. are you sure terraform is running on a network that has access to the private zones?


2. you are referencing a variable called `var.domains` in your question and i dont see it anywhere in your code.  are you actually referring to the `var.domain_name` (singular) variable?


3. have you tried this with only the private zone, and only the public zone, without the for_each?  did both work?


4. are you sure there are hosted zones by both names in your account?

Comment: 1. Yes, locally i was able to get the zone_id, its using the same credentials. 2. sorry , my bad it's a typo, everywhere `var.domain_name` 3 Its the same error when i don't use ` for_each` and works if list contains all public or all private domain_names. It fails when i add public and private domains.
4.Yes there are hosted_zones in my account,